# Integration gives wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Already several pages of stack exchange dedicated to the integration problem in Mathematica. However, by reading them I did not find solution to my own integral. I know from `NIntegrate` and other criteria that the answer of following integral:

```
Integrate[
  (16 Cos[k]^2 Sin[th]^4 + Sin[2 (k)]^2 Sin[2 th]^2) / 
    ( 16 (-1 + Cos[k]^2 Cos[th]^2)^2), 
  {k, -π + alpha, π + alpha}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True]
```

gives the following wrong answer

> ```
> -2 π Tan[th]^2
> ```

However, it gives different results by using `NIntegrate`?

```
Show @ 
  Table[
    Plot[{f[th, {0, 0.3, 0.5}[[i]]], -2 π Tan[ th]^2}, {th, -π, π}, 
      PlotStyle -> 
        {Directive[Dotted, {Black, Blue, Red}[[i]]], 
         Directive[Line, {Black, Blue, Red}[[i]]]}], 
    {i, 1, 3}]
```

where,

```
f[th_, alpha_] := NIntegrate[(16 Cos[k]^2 Sin[th]^4 + Sin[2 (k)]^2 Sin[2 th]^2)/(16 (-1 + Cos[k]^2 Cos[th]^2)^2), {k, -π + alpha, π + alpha}]
```

[image]

I would appreciate any comments or help.

Comment: Hello there! Please edit your question by providing more information so others can try to reproduce your results. Namely, what are `alpha` and `f`? What was the result you expected to get and how do you know the result you do get is wrong?

Comment: Plots `Plot[(16 Cos[k]^2 Sin[th]^4 + 
     Sin[2 (k)]^2 Sin[2 th]^2)/(16 (-1 + Cos[k]^2 Cos[th]^2)^2) /. 
  th -> 1/2, {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]` and `Plot[(16 Cos[k]^2 Sin[th]^4 + 
     Sin[2 (k)]^2 Sin[2 th]^2)/(16 (-1 + Cos[k]^2 Cos[th]^2)^2) /. 
  th -> -1, {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]` show no singularity.

Comment: Plot `Plot3D[(16 Cos[k]^2 Sin[th]^4 + 
    Sin[2 (k)]^2 Sin[2 th]^2)/(16 (-1 + 
       Cos[k]^2 Cos[th]^2)^2), {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {th, -Pi, Pi}]]` shows no singularity too. Therefore, the `PrincipalValue->True` option is superfluous.

Comment: @kiro, sorry for the late update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (16 Cos[k]^2 Sin[th]^4 + 
     Sin[2 (k)]^2 Sin[2 th]^2)/(16 (-1 + Cos[k]^2 Cos[th]^2)^2);

int1[th_] = 
 Integrate[expr, {k, -π + alpha, π + alpha}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

[image]

Adding some Assumptions,

```
int2[th_] = Assuming[{-Pi < th < Pi, 0 < alpha < 1},
  Integrate[expr, {k, -π + alpha, π + alpha}, PrincipalValue -> True]]

(* 2 π (-1 + Abs[Csc[th]]) Tan[th]^2 *)
```

The numeric integral is

```
int3[th_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[expr, {k, -π + 1/10, π + 1/10}]
```

Visually comparing the integrals

```
Plot[Evaluate@{int1[th] // Normal, int2[th], int3[th]},
  {th, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotRange -> {-10, 4},
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Dashed},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic] // Quiet
```

[image]

`int2` is consistent with the numeric integration

Comment: So I think we have to use your approach to other problems.  I mean putting integration in the assuming environment.

Comment: The problem is not with the assumptions, but as @Andreas says, that older versions "do not see the jumps of ArcTan at the poles of its argument", at k==-Pi/2 and Pi/2. A general workaround is to build the limit of the indefinite integral at these points (if function is not to complicated for Limit). See next comment. `int[k_] = Integrate[integrand, k] ` .

Comment: `(Limit[int[k], k -> Pi + alpha, Direction -> 1, 
    Assumptions -> 0 <= alpha < 1] - 
   Limit[int[k], k -> Pi/2, Direction -> -1] + 
   Limit[int[k], k -> Pi/2, Direction -> 1] - 
   Limit[int[k], k -> -Pi/2, Direction -> -1] + 
   Limit[int[k], k -> -Pi/2, Direction -> 1] - 
   Limit[int[k], k -> -Pi + alpha, Direction -> -1, 
    Assumptions -> 0 <= alpha < 1]) // Simplify ` yields   `2 \[Pi] (-1 + Sqrt[Csc[th]^2]) Tan[th]^2 ` .

Answer (score 7):

First: the function can be simplified to

```
1/(1 + Csc[th]^2 Tan[k]^2).
```

Then  you find the antiderivative

```
Integrate[1/(1 + Csc[th]^2 Tan[k]^2), k]
```

> ```
> Sec[th] (ArcTan[Csc[th] Tan[k]] - k Sin[th]) Tan[th].
> ```

The problem with the integral is that it doesn't see the jumps of the ArcTan at the poles of its argument,so it is not continuous. A continuous antiderivative is:

> ```
> Sec[th] (ArcTan[Csc[th] Tan[k]] - k Sin[th]) Tan[th] + π Sec[   th] Tan[th] Floor[k/π + 1/2].
> ```

This can be evaluated with your integration limits to:

> ```
> 2 π (Sec[th] - Tan[th]) Tan[th].
> ```

This agrees for π > th > 0 with Nintegrate numbers.

Comment: Solution for -Pi < th < Pi is `2 \[Pi] Sec[th] (Sign[Csc[th]] - Sin[th]) Tan[th]`